# haar cascade no detection

Tags: python, opencv

I am using the sample face and eye detection using Haar cascade code in cv2.
Now I am trying to modify the code so that i want trigger some code when the face is not detected.

```
while 1:
ret, img = cap.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
if k == 27:
    break
```

so if cascade detected: do nothing, else: some code here. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding for [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale) is that your variable `faces` is supposed to hold a list of detected objects containing matrices, which you then try to draw with rectangles in your for loop, so I would do it like so:

```
 faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

 if not faces:
     # do your code
 else:
     for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
         # Rest of the code
```